# equality condition in python django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would create a condition {% if ... %}  that allows me to compare the {{ looged_user }}  with the user's response {{ reply.user }}
The looged_user is the person connect
Reply.user is the response of a person
I would show only person logged answers

So I have try:

```
{% if '{{ logged_user }}' == '{{ reply.user }}' %}
```

or

```
{% if {{ logged_user }} == {{ reply.user }} %}
```

or

```
{% if logged_user == reply.user %}
```

But nothing works!

Nevertheless the logged user is equivalent to reply.user ...

My template :

```
{% for question in questions %}  
  {% for reply in question.reply_set.all %}
<hr>
    {{ logged_user }}<br>{{ reply.user }} --> {{ question }} : {{ reply.answer }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

you can see that they are well equal ..

The result of the screenshot:

[image]

when I try to add the condition this shows me nothing.

Comment: `{% if logged_user == reply.user %}` is the correct way. Are you sure both logged_user and reply.user are User objects? What's the output if you just print the ID's of both Users in the template? E.g. `{{ logged_user.id }} , {{ reply.user.id }}`

Comment: {{ logged_user.id }} , {{ reply.user.id }} return me 52 and 52 ... I dn't know why this conditions doesn't work

Comment: Strange... What's the output of the following: `{% if logged_user == reply.user %}equal{% else %}not equal{% endif %}`

Comment: i have write : {% if reply.user.id == logged_user.id %} in my condition and it's works ! I don't know why i need the id here but it's okay.. ^^' Thanks you !

Comment: Glad you got it to work :) But strange behaviour though...